# Creating A Dataframe From A Text Dataset

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have a dataset that has hundreds of thousands of fields. The following is a simplified dataset

```
dataSet <- c("Plnt SLoc Material           Description              L.T MRP Stat Auto MatSG PC PN    Freq  Qty    CFreq     CQty Cur.RPt New.RPt CurRepl NewRepl Updt    Cost   ServStock  Unit  OpenMatResb DFStorLocLevel", 
"0231 0002 GB.C152260-00001   ASSY PISTON & SEAL/O-RING 44  PD       X    A    A  A     18     136                     30      29      50      43         24.88      51.000  EA", 
"0231 0002 WH.112734          MOTOR REDUCER, THREE-PHAS 41  PD       X    B    B  A     16      17                      3       3       5       4        483.87       1.000  EA      X", 
"0231 0002 WH.920569          SPINDLE MOTOR MINI O      22  PD       X    A    A  A     69      85                     15       9      25      13        680.91      21.000  EA", 
"0231 0002 GB.C150583-00001   VALVE-AIR MDI             64  PD       X    A    A  A     16     113                     50      35      80      52         19.96     116.000  EA", 
"0231 0002 FG.124-0140        BEARING                   32  PD       X    A    A  A     36     205                     35      32      50      48         21.16      55.000  EA", 
"0231 0002 WP.254997          BEARING,BALL .9843 X 2.04 52  PD       X    A    A  A     18     155                     50      39     100      58          2.69     181.000  EA"
)
```

I would like to create a dataframe out of this dataSet for further calculation. The approach I am following is as follows:

I split the dataSet by space and then recombine it.

```
dataSetSplit <- strsplit(dataSet, "\\s+")
```

The header (which is the first line) splits correctly and produces 25 characters. This can be seen by the str() function.

```
str(dataSetSplit)
```

I will then intend to combine all the rows together using the folloing script

```
combinedData  <-  data.frame(do.call(rbind, dataSetSplit))
```

Please note that the above script "combinedData " errors because the split did not produce equal number of fields.

For this approach to work all the fields must split correctly into 25 fields.

If you think this is a sound approach **please let me know how to split the fileds into 25 fields**.

It is worth mentioning that I do not like the approach of splitting the data set with the function strsplit(). It is an extremely time consuming step if used with a large data set. **Can you please recommend an alternate approach to create a data frame out of the supplied data?**

Comment: This looks like it's fixed width data. Look at `read.fwf` instead.

Comment: How did you load the data in the firstplace?

Comment: This is related to the posting at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067027/deleting-words-from-within-r/23083813#23083813

Comment: Did my answer stop working or something? If so, a comment helps to explain why the "accepted" status was removed, thus indicating that this problem is still unsolved. Solved questions is what makes SO a valuable resource for others trying to solve similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to Ananda Mahto, he provided many pieces to this answer.

```
widthMinusFirst <- diff(gregexpr('(\\s[A-Z])+', dataSet[1])[[1]])
widthFirst <- gregexpr('\\s+', dataSet[1])[[1]][1]
Width <- c(widthFirst, widthMinusFirst)

Widths <- c(Width, max(nchar(dataSet)) - sum(Width))
columnNames <- scan(what = "", text = dataSet[1])

read.fwf(textConnection(dataSet[-1]), widths = Widths, strip.white = FALSE,
         skip = 0, col.names = columnNames)
```

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of it, you have a header row that is actually helpful. You can easily use `gregexpr` to calculate your "widths" to use with `read.fwf`.

Here's how:

```
## Use gregexpr to find the position of consecutive runs of spaces
## This will tell you the starting position of each column
Widths <- gregexpr("\\s+", dataSet[1])[[1]]

## `read.fwf` doesn't need the starting position, but the width of
##   each column. We can use `diff` to calculate this. 
Widths <- c(Widths[1], diff(Widths))

## Since there are no spaces after the last column, we need to calculate
##   a reasonable width for that column too. We can do this with `nchar`
##   to find the widest row in the data. From this, subtract the `sum`
##   of all the previous values.
Widths <- c(Widths, max(nchar(dataSet)) - sum(Widths))
```

Let's also extract the column names. We could do this in `read.fwf`, but it would require us to substitute the spaces in the first line with a "sep" character.

```
Names <- scan(what = "", text = dataSet[1])
```

Now, read in everything except the first line. You would use the actual file instead of `textConnection`, I would suppose.

```
read.fwf(textConnection(dataSet), widths=Widths, strip.white = TRUE, 
         skip = 1, col.names = Names)
#   Plnt SLoc         Material               Description L.T MRP Stat Auto MatSG PC PN Freq Qty
# 1  231    2 GB.C152260-00001 ASSY PISTON & SEAL/O-RING  44  PD   NA    X     A  A  A   18 136
# 2  231    2        WH.112734 MOTOR REDUCER, THREE-PHAS  41  PD   NA    X     B  B  A   16  17
# 3  231    2        WH.920569      SPINDLE MOTOR MINI O  22  PD   NA    X     A  A  A   69  85
# 4  231    2 GB.C150583-00001             VALVE-AIR MDI  64  PD   NA    X     A  A  A   16 113
# 5  231    2      FG.124-0140                   BEARING  32  PD   NA    X     A  A  A   36 205
# 6  231    2        WP.254997 BEARING,BALL .9843 X 2.04  52  PD   NA    X     A  A  A   18 155
#   CFreq CQty Cur.RPt New.RPt CurRepl NewRepl Updt   Cost ServStock Unit OpenMatResb
# 1    NA   NA      30      29      50      43   NA  24.88        51   EA        <NA>
# 2    NA   NA       3       3       5       4   NA 483.87         1   EA           X
# 3    NA   NA      15       9      25      13   NA 680.91        21   EA        <NA>
# 4    NA   NA      50      35      80      52   NA  19.96       116   EA        <NA>
# 5    NA   NA      35      32      50      48   NA  21.16        55   EA        <NA>
# 6    NA   NA      50      39     100      58   NA   2.69       181   EA        <NA>
#   DFStorLocLevel
# 1             NA
# 2             NA
# 3             NA
# 4             NA
# 5             NA
# 6             NA
```

Comment: Ananda Mahto, can you please provide an explanation of the three Widths scripts? Thanks

Comment: Hi Ananda, `diff` does not calculate the width of each column correctly. For example column 3 'Material' calculated width is 9 but in fact it is supposed to be 19
Widths <- c(Widths[1], diff(Widths))

Comment: I think the object 'Width' + number of trailing spaces should equal the column width. The key is to extract the number of trailing spaces for each column.

Comment: @RagyIsaac, I must have had some residual information in my workspace on which I was doing the calculations. I'll look again later when I have a chance.