# loading space separated data on R?

Tags: r

I want to read ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt into a R data frame.

The problem is that the file is not comma separated and that some columns are empty for some observations.

I tried to run:

```
test <- read.table("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/ghcnd-stations.txt", header = FALSE)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
```

line 1 did not have 9 elements

Any idea of how can I do this?

Thanks!

---

This is probably useful to answer the question:

```
------------------------------
Variable   Columns   Type
------------------------------
ID            1-11   Character
LATITUDE     13-20   Real
LONGITUDE    22-30   Real
ELEVATION    32-37   Real
STATE        39-40   Character
NAME         42-71   Character
GSNFLAG      73-75   Character
HCNFLAG      77-79   Character
WMOID        81-85   Character
------------------------------
```

Comment: Try `read.fwf` instead.

Comment: is there an easy way to determine the widths that i should use?

Comment: Count :-) I don't see an easy way in this case. Alternatively, many spreadsheet programs (even Excel) will let you visually set the widths on reading the data in, and from there, you can either convert to a CSV, copy and paste, or use one of the many other tricks to get the data into R.

Comment: Alternatively, see if the website offers a schema file that describes the dataset. Those sometimes mention the widths.

Comment: The answer is right there in your update.... That's the schema that I just mentioned.

Comment: The widths should be widths=c(11,8,9,6,2,30,3,3,5) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the schema file, so from there, it shouldn't be too much work.

Read the schema file in.

```
Schema <- read.table(text = "ID            1-11   Character
LATITUDE     13-20   Real
LONGITUDE    22-30   Real
ELEVATION    32-37   Real
STATE        39-40   Character
NAME         42-71   Character
GSNFLAG      73-75   Character
HCNFLAG      77-79   Character
WMOID        81-85   Character", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Split the second column and extract the upper part of the range. Then, use `diff` to find out the `widths`:

```
Widths <- as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(as.character(Schema$V2), "-"), `[`, 2))
Widths <- c(Widths[1], diff(Widths))
Widths
# [1] 11  9 10  7  3 31  4  4  6
```

Now, you can use `read.fwf`. The schema file also provides the column names for us.

```
out <- read.fwf("~/Downloads/ghcnd-stations.txt", widths = Widths, 
                col.names = Schema$V1, strip.white = TRUE, comment.char = "")
head(out)
#            ID LATITUDE LONGITUDE ELEVATION STATE                  NAME GSNFLAG HCNFLAG WMOID
# 1 ACW00011604  17.1167  -61.7833      10.1       ST JOHNS COOLIDGE FLD                    NA
# 2 ACW00011647  17.1333  -61.7833      19.2                    ST JOHNS                    NA
# 3 AE000041196  25.3330   55.5170      34.0         SHARJAH INTER. AIRP     GSN         41196
# 4 AF000040930  35.3170   69.0170    3366.0                NORTH-SALANG     GSN         40930
# 5 AG000060390  36.7167    3.2500      24.0          ALGER-DAR EL BEIDA     GSN         60390
# 6 AG000060590  30.5667    2.8667     397.0                    EL-GOLEA     GSN         60590
```

The key to the `widths` argument is specifying the number of columns for each field and, using negative numbers, the number of columns between fields.

Your file contained "#" in some rows, which is treated as a comment character in R. Setting `comment.char = ""` resets this and let's you read the file without any problem.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Go for it.

Comment: I kept your note about negative numbers, but they generally aren't really required if you're also going to use `strip.white = TRUE`.

Comment: I think I've [had my share](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23090025/1270695) of `read.fwf` for the day.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas' answer is very good, I would just add that you could used the strip.white argument to remove any additional blanks R finds in character data values

```
mydata <- read.fwf(
+    file="mydataFWF.txt",
+    width=c(11,-2,7,-3,7,-1,6,-1,2,-1,30,-1,3,-5,5),
+    na.strings="",
+    fill=TRUE,
+    strip.white=TRUE)
```

Also you'll often get the warning

```
 In readLines(file, n = thisblock) :
 incomplete final line found on ’mydataFWF.txt’
```

but you can either safely ignore it or just add a line break at the end of your text file.