# How to create schema table to read data when the schema follows a pattern

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a schema table in order to read some data using read.fwf. The idea is to end up doing the same thing that is done in [loading space separated data on R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090393/loading-space-separated-data-on-r?noredirect=1#comment35293055_23090393)

My problem is that the schema is much more complicated and writing it by hand seems like a bad idea.

This is basically what I want to write:

```
Schema <- read.table(text = "ID            1-11   Character
                            YEAR         12-15   Integer
                            MONTH        16-17   Integer
                            ELEMENT      18-21   Character
                            VALUE1       22-26   Integer
                            MFLAG1       27-27   Character
                            QFLAG1       28-28   Character
                            SFLAG1       29-29   Character
                            VALUE2       30-34   Integer
                            MFLAG2       35-35   Character
                            QFLAG2       36-36   Character
                            SFLAG2       37-37   Character
                            VALUE3       38-42   Integer
                            MFLAG3       43-43   Character
                            QFLAG3       44-44   Character
                            SFLAG3       45-45   Character
                            VALUE4       46-50   Integer
                            MFLAG4       51-51   Character
                            QFLAG4       52-52   Character
                            SFLAG4       53-53   Character
                            .           .          .
                            .           .          .
                            .           .          .
                            VALUE31    262-266   Integer
                            MFLAG31    267-267   Character
                            QFLAG31    268-268   Character
                            SFLAG31    269-269   Character", 
                     header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

There is a clear pattern that I think should be possible to replicate using a do loop and paste. For example, VALUE4       54-58   Integer etc etc.

Do I have the right idea? Can someone show me how to implement it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do Widths = c(11, 4, 2, 4, rep(c(5, 1, 1, 1), times = 31)), but what about the columns names? That part I have to write a do loop using paste to generate the vector? My understanding is that do loops should be avoided in R. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, the structure of this schema is very predictable. You really just need to get comfortable with `rep` to be able to piece together what you need.

Here are all the pieces we need:

```
Widths <- c(11, 4, 2, 4, rep(c(5, 1, 1, 1), times = 31))

Names <- c("ID", "YEAR", "MONTH", "ELEMENT", 
           paste0(c("VALUE", "MFLAG", "QFLAG", "SFLAG"), 
                  rep(1:31, each = 4)))

Classes <- c("character", "integer", "character", "character",
             rep(c("integer", "character", "character", "character"), 
                 times = 31))
```

I'd recommend using the "Classes" column since we have it since that will help `read.fwf` process the file a little faster.

Now, let's put the pieces to use:

```
out <- read.fwf(
    "ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/ghcn/daily/gsn/AQW00061705.dly",
    widths = Widths, header = FALSE, col.names = Names,  colClasses = Classes)
```

And, let's view the structure of the first few columns and the last few columns to see if it matches with what we expected:

```
str(out[c(1:10, 120:128)])
# data.frame':  10245 obs. of  19 variables:
#  $ ID     : chr  "AQW00061705" "AQW00061705" "AQW00061705" "AQW00061705" ...
#  $ YEAR   : int  1966 1966 1966 1966 1966 1966 1966 1966 1966 1966 ...
#  $ MONTH  : chr  "04" "04" "04" "04" ...
#  $ ELEMENT: chr  "TMAX" "TMIN" "PRCP" "SNOW" ...
#  $ VALUE1 : int  328 222 117 0 0 40 60 48 342 315 ...
#  $ MFLAG1 : chr  " " " " " " " " ...
#  $ QFLAG1 : chr  " " " " " " " " ...
#  $ SFLAG1 : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
#  $ VALUE2 : int  311 233 168 0 0 60 90 56 402 270 ...
#  $ MFLAG2 : chr  " " " " " " " " ...
#  $ SFLAG29: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
#  $ VALUE30: int  300 239 216 0 0 90 90 9 60 135 ...
#  $ MFLAG30: chr  " " " " " " " " ...
#  $ QFLAG30: chr  " " " " " " " " ...
#  $ SFLAG30: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
#  $ VALUE31: int  -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 ...
#  $ MFLAG31: chr  " " " " " " " " ...
#  $ QFLAG31: chr  " " " " " " " " ...
#  $ SFLAG31: chr  " " " " " " " " ...
```